# Need to send multiple AndroidFastNetworking Requests in sequence

Tags: android, android-networking

Imagine I have 2 functions. `function1();` and `function2();` both of them has an `AndroidNetworking.post` method. My problem is the `function2()` sometimes response faster than`function1()`. How can I make `function2();` waits `function1();` to finish responding to our server?

Answer (score 0):

You asked a very abstract question. Here's an abstract answer. This is a rough code, but it will work. Tell me if you meant something else.

```
 public void callFunctions(Callback callback){
    int[] x = new int[1];
    fc1(() -> {
        x[0]++;
        if(x[0] == 2)callback.callback();
    });
    fc2(() -> {
        x[0]++;
        if(x[0] == 2)callback.callback();
    });
}

public void fc1(Callback callback){
    //  ... Networking
    callback.callback();    //  In main thread!
}

public void fc2(Callback callback){
    //  ... Networking
    callback.callback();    //  In main thread!
}

public interface Callback {

    void callback();

}
```

Comment: what Callback do you imported?

Comment: so if i use this it will go like this?

Comment: `public void fc2(Callback callback){
   function1();
    callback.callback();    //  In main thread!
}`

Comment: can we move to chat room?

Comment: @Mike, i can, but I'll be free in an hour. And I do not know how to get into the chat, you have to explain it to me. :)

Comment: I don't know how to move to to chat. :(

Comment: @Mike, mail me to zeooon@ya.ru